# QML: two checkboxes in the same toolbar are overlapped - cannot set position

Tags: checkbox, qml, qtquick2

I have a toolbar with two checkboxes, which are correctly generated, but I cannot set their position, and so they are placed one on top of the other.

```
header : ToolBar {
    CheckBox {
       id: autoLoadButtonTB
       checked: true
       text: qsTr("Auto &Load")    //TODO 'L' should be underlined
       action: autoLoadAction
    }
    CheckBox {
       id: autoSaveButtonTB
       checked: true
       text: qsTr("&Auto Save")    //TODO 'A' should be underlined
       action: autoSaveAction
    }
}
```

Is it possible to have them one next to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls-toolbar.html, it demonstrates the `ToolBar` with a `RowLayout`. If we apply that to your example, we get:

```
    header : ToolBar {
        RowLayout {
            CheckBox {
                id: autoLoadButtonTB
                checked: true
                text: qsTr("Auto &Load")    //TODO 'L' should be underlined
                action: autoLoadAction
            }
            CheckBox {
                id: autoSaveButtonTB
                checked: true
                text: qsTr("&Auto Save")    //TODO 'A' should be underlined
                action: autoSaveAction
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, you may like to consider replacing `CheckBox` with `ToolButton` or `MenuItem` with `checkable: true`. They function similarly to a `CheckBox` but, they're look may be more consistent with what's needed for `ToolBar`.